# How to automatically register @Entity decorated classes at application start up?

Tags: java, objectify, google-app-engine

#### How you do enable Objectify to automatically discover your annotated `Entity` classes at runtime?

I want to register my classes at application start up and not have to hard code them into a class as recommended in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

This is no `runtime` reflection cost solution because it does all the reflection at `compile/build/package` time.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * This class processes the classpath for classes with the @Entity or @Subclass annotations from Objectify
 * and registers them with the ObjectifyFactory, it is multi-threaded and works very fast!
 */
public class ObjectifyLoaderContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    private static final Logger L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ObjectifyLoaderContextListener.class);

    private final Set<Class<?>> entities;

    public ObjectifyLoaderContextListener()
    {
        this.entities = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(@Nonnull final ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        final ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory());
        cb.setExecutorService(es);
        final Reflections r = Reflections.collect();
        this.entities.addAll(r.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class));
        es.shutdown();
        final ObjectifyFactory of = ObjectifyService.factory();
        for (final Class<?> cls : this.entities)
        {
            of.register(cls);
            L.debug("Registered {} with Objectify", cls.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(@Nonnull final ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        /* this is intentionally empty */
    }
}
```

Updates to this class will be available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jarrodhroberson/6243e6006b3190369192).

Comment: The new version with Reflections.collect(); makes sense to me. You may also want to mention the steps to integrate Reflections into the build cycle (which is what allows the use of the #collect API and reduces the runtime component of this solution drastically) with a link to some example.

Comment: where is cb defined?

Answer (score -1):

Here's an alternative solution building on the accepted answer.

**Summary**
If you want to eliminate all production runtime cost from your service (even the relatively small one of picking up the XML artifacts which are then consumed by the #collect API), you can move the cost to the unit testing stage while still retaining 100% safety in prod of all entities being registered. See end of answer for code.

**Motivation & Details**
This has several benefits as outlined below, though whether they are worth it is up to your use case. To me personally, it isn't whether any of these are ever going to be a problem -- it's more that given the option to avoid doing anything unnecessary in production (and deleting code from production paths), I would always take it, as long as it doesn't entail extra complexity, weird design costs, etc. In this case there are none. This is a text-book approach of moving runtime registration guarantees from prod to testing.

Note that GAE instances may get restarted arbitrarily many times. Other considerations include how sensitive your app is to service startup times, how large the generated Reflection XML artifacts are (a function of your jar dependencies and impl details of the Reflection 3rd party library), and how efficiently the library parses them. While you can mitigate performance risk with multi-threading, google still charges you for CPU time used.

The relative benefits of converting this to a unit test solution are:

1. you eliminate the cost of parsing XML resources and reconstructing them into Reflection metadata each time your service is restarted (may happen arbitrarily many times)
2. you eliminate the risk of changing your project JAR dependencies at some future times (dependencies tend to grown over time for non-trivial projects) and forgetting to re-assess new size of XML resources and their parsing; this may start adding more sizeable overhead to your service restart time gradually, which is hard to pinpoint but affects users (contributing to the classic death-by-a-thousand-cuts)
3. you eliminate a runtime prod dependency on a 3rd library which is always good (the dependency will remain for your unit testing modules). For instance, if a future version of the library suddenly regresses on XML parsing speeds, you will need to deal with that in prod. It's a risk that can be eliminated.

Whether these considerations remain purely academic depends on your use case and risk/cost tolerance.

*Caveat: if for some reason your release rollout process does not mandate passing unit tests, this clearly isn't the right approach. But I don't think that would be the case for many people.*

**Code**
I've omitted the outer test class for readability (assume all code lives in a Test class)

```
@Test
public void testObjectifyRegistration() {
    final ObjectifyFactory ofy = Ofy.factory(); // your backend-specific ofy entry point  where you've done your registrations
    for (final Class<?> cls : allEntities()) {
        verifyRegistrationState(ofy, cls, /*expected to be registered?*/!cls.equals(UnregisteredUnittestEntity.class));
    }
}

private Iterable<Class<?>> allEntities() {
    final ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    try {
        final ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(""));
        cb.setExecutorService(es);
        return new HashSet<>(new Reflections(cb).getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class));
    } finally {
        es.shutdown();
    }
}

private void verifyRegistrationState(final ObjectifyFactory ofy, final Class<?> cls, final boolean shouldBeRegistered) {
    RuntimeException missingRegistrationExc = null;
    try {
        ofy.getMetadata(cls); // per today's API contract, this method throws if cls has not been registered with objectify
    } catch (RuntimeException exc) {
        missingRegistrationExc = exc;
    }
    if (shouldBeRegistered && missingRegistrationExc != null)
        throw missingRegistrationExc;
    else if (!shouldBeRegistered && missingRegistrationExc == null)
        fail("ObjectifyFactory#getMetadata expected to throw upon unregistered entity, check for new contract of method and update test");
}

@Entity // self-test: used to validate correctness of the unit test itself
private static class UnregisteredUnittestEntity {
    @VisibleForTesting
    public UnregisteredUnittestEntity() {
    }
}
```

And below is an example failure when a class annotated with `@Entity` has not been registered with `Objectify`.

> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class '[xxx].UserImpl' was
>   registered**  at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Registrar.getMetadataSafe(Registrar.java:120)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.getMetadata(ObjectifyFactory.java:210)
>     at
>   [xxx].OfyRegistrationTest.verifyRegistrationState(OfyRegistrationTest.java:56)
>     at
>   [xxx].OfyRegistrationTest.testOfyRegistration(OfyRegistrationTest.java:37)